# Groovy loop command and break if it meets a criteria and return false

Tags: groovy

Hello folks I have the following scenario:
I will check with a command if a curl returns 200.
I want to check several endpoints and the end if ALL the endpoints return 200 then the function to be "TRUE".
I'm new to groovy and googled a bit,  but I struggle to understand the login on how to achieve that.
Here is one of the tests I did in groovy console, but I can't wrap that to make it work

```
  def mytest(){
    def a = [200, 200, 200, 300]
    
    a.find {
        if (it == 200) return true // break
        println it  // do the stuff that you wanted to before break
        return false // keep looping
    }
    }
    if (!mytest()) {
    println "Function returns false"
    }
```

Comment: `but I can't wrap that to make it work` - what do you mean by this? do you have error?

Comment: Not an error, but I dont get the required result, which is the function to break when meeting a number that is not 200 and return false

Answer (score 0):

here is code close to yours. but in case when `a` contains `null` the final result could be wrong.

```
def a = [200, 200, 200, 300]

def non200found = a.find {
    if (it == 200) return false // false to continue searching
    println it  // do the stuff that you wanted to before break
    return true // return true to notify that non-200 found
}

return non200found!=null
```

let's switch from `find` to `any`:

```
def a = [200, 200, 200, 300]

return !a.any{
    if (it == 200) return false // false to continue searching
    println it  // do the stuff that you wanted to before break
    return true // return true to notify that non-200 found
}
```

Comment: I think `a.find {it!=200}` fails to satisfy the requirements.  If the input list is `[200, 0, 200]` your code will behave the same as if the input list is `[200, 200, 200]` and fail to recognize the non-200 in the list.  That is because `find` will return `null` if no matches are found and will return `0` when `0` is found, and both of those evaluate to `false` per Groovy truth rules.